# Sql Server Replication running slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

We set up replication on one of our database and in a publication there are 25 tables. In the replication monitor performance is showing excellent, but when i check in the details and went to undistributed commands it is still showing some 15 Mill.
Any one had this issue before.?

Comment: can You specify replication type and amount of data?

Comment: Transnational Replication and all the data is getting replicated on to subscriber and shows no latency but when i check undistributed commands it was 1.5Mill this morning and now it is 1.9Million.

Comment: I personally think replication monitor is not great at… monitoring replication. I use tracer tokens as the gold standard. If you insert a token now, where does it say the latency is? That is, "publisher to distributor" or "distributor to subscriber"? If expect the latter but it's good to verify. You'll also get time to delivery from that token which is useful.

Comment: There is no latency. Pub to dist it is 1 sec and dist to sub 2 secs..